# Controller Action Raising An Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a controller Method names `process_message` and the purpose of it is to sign people up to specific groups depending on what message it receives. Right now everything works just fine except it will sign up a person to the same group over and over again. I'm trying to add some quick code to make it so they can only sign up to a specific group once. I thought that I figured it out but I am getting an error when I try to execute what I've written. Ill show some screenshots and some code for clarity.

Here is my controller method

```
def process_message
if message_params[:action] == 'subscribe'
  # result = SubscribeToGroup.call(message_params)
  # results.success? ? result.message : result.error
  message_params[:id] = "visitor" if message_params[:id] == "tulip" # hack for now
  @group = Group.find_by(name: message_params[:id])     
  if @group && @subscriber.groups << @group unless groups.include? (@group)                                                  ^
    @group.response
  else
    'You cannot subscribe to unknown group'
  end
elsif message_params[:action] == 'stop'
  # result = UnsubscribeToGroup.call(message_params)
  # results.success? ? result.message : result.error
  group_name = message_params[:id]
  @group = @subscriber.groups.find_by(name: group_name)
  @subscriber.groups.destroy(@group) if @group
  "You are now unsubscribed from #{group_name.upcase} notifications. Text '#{group_name.upcase}' to start receieving updates again."
else
  "Sorry, we don't recognize that command."
end
rescue Exception => e
"Something went wrong. Try again. #{e.message}"
end
```

You can see on the 7th line I have some code there that I thought would keep the message from signing up a person twice but it isn't working and here is the error message when I run Rspec.

[image]

I hope my problem is clear let me know if you need anymore code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd avoid putting an `if` and an `unless` on the same line

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
# You may have meant to provide `@subscriber.groups` instead of `groups` here. I'm not sure from information provided.
unless groups.include?(@group) 
  @subscriber.groups << @group 
end

if @group && @subscriber.groups.present?
# ...
```

Comment: Maybe? I get a `undefined method "<<" for false:FalseClass` now

Comment: Thanks for the help Anthony, but I'm still getting an error that says groups is  an undefined local variable now

Comment: Yeah, did you mean to provide `@subscribers.groups`? see the comment above my edit.

Comment: Yep you got it! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You have `if` and `unless` in one line. That gives you the syntax error.

The logic is not clear here.
Maybe what you want can just be done by adding a newline, so that the unless-statement is inside the if-block and not the if-condition.

```
if @group.present? 
    @subscriber.groups << @group unless groups.include? (@group)                                                  
    @group.response
else
    'You cannot subscribe to unknown group'
end
```

Comment: any ideas on how I could do it?